# Cannot POST using Rest API

Tags: python, django

So I can retrieve my data perfectly fine but when I try to post I get

```
{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
```

views.py

```
class ClubFullList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Club.objects.all()

class ClubList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Club.objects.filter(abv=username)
```

models.py

```
class Club(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        abv = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

serializers.py

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = ['name', 'abv']
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending **POST** request on an endpoint which only allows **GET** request.

`ListAPIView` is a  **read-only** generic view. To create model objects using POST request, use [`CreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) or [`ListCreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview).

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs for ListApiView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview):

> Used for **read-only** endpoints to represent a collection of model instances.

If you want to post to your endpoint, you'll need to use a different view class.